# How to only "link_to" user's tags?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, tags

I have this `tag_cloud`

```
<% tag_cloud(@user_tags, %w(css1 css2 css3 css4)) do |tag, css_class| %>
  <%= link_to tag.name, tag_path(tag.name), :class => css_class %>
<% end %>
```

Right now if I click on "run" in my `tag_cloud` I will be redirected to:

http://www.personalcontrolcenter.com/tags/run

where it then lists out all the tags with "run", including those from other users. How can we only list out the tags from the current user?

**routes.rb**   `get 'tags/:tag', to: 'pages#home', as: :tag`

I'm using the acts-as-taggable-gem. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The route you're using via `tag_path` in `link_to` sends the tag to `PagesController#home`. If you only want to show the tags of current user you should only load those in that controller action.

Comment: Good call! I don't know if this is related to the problem, but do you have any idea why when I click on the link_to of a tag and I am brought to the list of those tags that they are all duplicating?